# How to know missing sound libraries when moving garage project to new device

Tags: garageband

I have a GarageBand project, created on my iPad.
I have moved the project to my iPhone, but it says that I am missing sound libraries - but it does not tell my which one?

1. I would expect to be told which libraries to download?
2. If I go back to the project on my iPad, I can not see which libraries I actually used?

I know I can see packages on the device in “manage packs” but not for the project.